# TabLayout selected Tab icon is not selected on start up

Tags: android, tabs, icons, android-tablayout, android-selector

I'm using a `TabLayout` for Tabbed navigation in my app. I have a really weird issue with it, I have created 4 tabs using this code:

```
private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.navigation_timeline_icon_selector, R.drawable.navigation_feed_icon_selector,
        R.drawable.navigation_messages_icon_selector, R.drawable.navigation_notification_icon_selector};

 TabLayout tabLayout = setTabLayout();
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
        }
    }
```

Each of the items in tabIcon is a `selector` with selected and non-selected states. All icon selectors are configured as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_timeline_selected_icon" android:state_selected="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_timeline_selected_icon" android:state_pressed="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigation_timeline_icon" />
</selector>
```

The problem is that when the application starts the first selected tab (index 0) does not use the selected state icon. Instead it uses the non-selected state.

To be more explanatory here is a screenshot of the issue, on first start my tab looks like this:

[image]

when instead it should be like this:

[image]

After I change a page all the icons come back to full functionality, and the selected states are selected properly.

I tried to use the `TabLayout.Tab select()` method but the result is the same the icon that is used is the not selected icon.

Does someone know what I can do to fix it?

Comment: @MsYvette what does that mean and how can it be handled?

Comment: @MsYvette You want to see the selector?

Comment: Yes it looks like your are right, I think I missing a state in my selector, testing it right now.

Comment: @MsYvette well the selector's changes didn't fix the problem, for some reason it's still not selected. continue looking for a solution.

Comment: @MsYvette selector code added.

Comment: Hi @EmilAdz Do we have a solution to this issue already?

Comment: @Elye, well emirua's answer works in case all of you tabs are custom views. Another thing you can do (if they are not) is select a second tab and then select the first one on start up. that will result in a selected first tab but also in calling the onTabSelected if you have a OnTabSelectedListener attached to the TabLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer for tab selection in `TabLayout` would be:

```
TabLayout.Tab currentTab = mTabs.getTabAt(selectedTab);
if (currentTab != null) {
    View customView = currentTab.getCustomView();
    if (customView != null) {
        customView.setSelected(true);
    }
    currentTab.select();
}
```

where `currentTab.select()` will move the indicator to the selected tab, when `customView.setSelected()` will make all the items in the custom view set their selected states from the selectors look selected.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

`tabLayout.getTabAt(yourInitialPosition).getCustomView().setSelected(true);`

Comment: I don't have a "getCustomView()" method, because I didn't added my tabs as custom view but as simple plain icons. So even if this works, I can't use this solution.

Comment: getCustomView is a public method from the TabLayout.Tab class, so you must have it and in this case it will return the drawable selector that you are applying to this tab. I don't get why you can't use it if it works. Maybe I'm missing something.. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: And if you can't use this solution, you can always just change the selection to a different tab and then switch back to the initial position  programatically.

Comment: You are right, getCustomView is indeed a public method but unless you set your tab as a custom view and not a icon tab, you can't use that method.

Comment: @Emil So you can try tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select(); although it doesn't work if you do have a custom view.

Comment: Perfect! I had initially tried `tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select()`, but that didn't work. This solution had the missing ingredient

Comment: This is not working if I don't have a custom view for tabs!

Answer (score 3):

I used in my tabLayout the xml selector for the icons with the following states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ajuda_off"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ajuda_on"/>
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ajuda_on"/>
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_ajuda_on"/>
```

and in the code:

```
private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.ic_tab_sites, R.drawable.ic_tab_help,
        R.drawable.ic_tab_profile, R.drawable.ic_tab_notification, R.drawable.ic_tab_search};

if (tabLayout != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
    }
}
```

It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the tab after you've populated them.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = setTabLayout();
if (tabLayout != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(tabIcons[i]);
    }
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
}
```

Comment: like I said: I tried to use the TabLayout.Tab select() method but the result is the same the icon that is used is the not selected icon.

Comment: Yes, saw it now... actually I think that first tab is also selected by default. the issue is not that the tab is not getting selected, but the fact the wrong icon is used.

Comment: what do you mean by this question? each time another tab is getting selected. On start up the 0 indexed tab should be selected.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution, 
paste this code in you **onCreate** Activity because using tabs 0 index not triggers directly this is easy way to do

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1)
    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only wanted to add the vector drawable to the selector file by it's not working so if you want to use Vector drawable you MUST add them as separated files...

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/stnkb_tab_recent_selected_true" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/stnkb_tab_recent_selected_false" />
```