# How to default set a tab on starting and set the icon color on selection of a tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablayout, fragment-tab-host

I am using a tablayout and a frame layout.

- I have five tabs.
- I am loading my fragments to this frame layouts.
- i want my second tab to defaultly get selected always.

Also when i select a perticular tab, the icon should change the color to red(I am using png icons, which are black , is their any way to change them to red to indicate that it is selected)

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/simple_tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@color/colorWhite"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#f00"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#f00"
    app:tabTextColor="#000"
    />


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity

```
     pb.setIcon(R.drawable.p_icon); // pb is my  TabLayout.Tab
    mb.setIcon(R.drawable.view_p_icon);
    gb.setIcon(R.drawable.c_icon);
    ptTab.setIcon(R.drawable.c_icon);


    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
        {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_home, new UF()).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_home, new DF()).commit();
                    showAlertDialog("Logout?");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_home, new SF()).commit();
                    showAlertDialog("Logout?");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_home, new SF()).commit();
                    showAlertDialog("Logout?");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_home, new SF()).commit();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: yes when you change select the tab you get it's position. and then you can either replace the icon with red background or change the color of icon background on tab selection.\

Comment: Posibble Duplicate of 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392640/tablayout-selected-tab-icon-is-not-selected-on-start-up

Comment: Or, if you don't want to do it programatically, just create a `selector` with 2 states `selected` & `default` and you set the color or background of selected and default items. Then you just use the selector in your tag item xml :D

Comment: ok ,but how to defaultly  load a tab on begining @lonut J. Bejan

Answer (score 0):

Add code for `setColorFilter` method in `onTabSelected()` method. It will change color for image .

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();

            if (tabPosition == 0) {
                // active tabName
                imageOne.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                // other deactive tabName
                imageTwo.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageThree.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageFour.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
            } else if (tabPosition == 1) {
                // active tabName
                imageTwo.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                // other deactive tabName
                imageOne.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageThree.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageFour.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
            } else if (tabPosition == 2) {
                // active tabName
                imageThree.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                // other deactive tabName
                imageTwo.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageOne.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageFour.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
            } else if (tabPosition == 3) {
                // active tabName
                imageFour.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.redColor));
                // other deactive tabName
                imageTwo.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageThree.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
                imageOne.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blackcolor));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
        }
    });
```

To select tab as default .

**If use with viewPager then** ,

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);  // set any number of tab which you want to select by default.
```

**If use without viewPager then** ,

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(someIndex);  // which you want to select.
tab.select();
```

Hope it Helps.

Comment: how to defaultly load a tab on begining @Dharmishtha

Comment: means to  set any one  tab selected as default?

Comment: yes, i need to set the tab 2 as default one @Dharmishtha

Comment: have you set viewPager like this ? `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);`

Comment: @Martinj  Have you use viewPager or not?

Comment: no i am not using a view pager, with out it can you suggest some method @Dharmishtha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160778/discussion-between-dharmishtha-and-martin-j).